# Section, figure, table numbers are in smaller font size

Tags: tables, floats, sectioning, fontsize

I have used `\include{resultsanddiscussion}` to import certain chapter **results and discussion**. I have used `\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\selectfont` to determine heading size 16 pt and spacing 18 pt. the code of the chapter is bellow,

`\chapter{\fontsize{16pt}{18pt}\selectfont{Experiments, Results and Discussions}}
\label{chap:ExperimentsResultsandDiscussion}`

But it creates problem like **chapter number remains smaller**, it is may be 14 pt. How can I make the chapter number same as the heading. For more details, as I am using a specific templates packages like `\usepackage{titlesec}` or `\usepackage{sectsty}` is not working for me. Here is a screen shot:

[image: screen.shot]

same probelm is also being generated for the **Figure number** and **Table number**. But I guess if the *heading number* can make in same size, other two can be solved in the same way.

Any suggestion please.

Comment: Can you please show us a small example code, that reproduces your problem?

Comment: the first part of my problem has been solved using installing sectsty.sty package separately. But the second problem, figure numbering  is still in lower font `\begin{figure}[!htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{images/horizonvertical}
\caption{\fontsize{12pt}{14pt}\selectfont{\textbf{bla bla caption}}
\label{fig:horizonvertical}
\end{figure}`